# What will log file be written when the hostname is changed?

Tags: linux, hostname

What will log file be written when the hostname is changed? and how do I learn the previous hostnames?
p.s there is not seen at the /var/log/messages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What log file will be written when the hostname is changed?

None.

> There is no file that contains this history. Perhaps you may be able to pull it out of syslog, but you're going to have to go searching for it.

Source [Hostname changes history in unix systems](https://serverfault.com/a/711030/251339), answer by [EEAA](https://serverfault.com/users/20815/eeaa)

And:

> Have a look at these files:
>
> ```
> /etc/hostname
> /etc/hosts
> /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*_key.pub
> $HOME/.ssh/id_*.pub
> ```
>
> In these typically the host name appears and it might be still
>   unchanged by your renaming action (however you did that).
>
> Also these might contain the old name:
>
> ```
> /var/log/Xorg.failsafe.log
> /var/log/auth.log.1
> /var/log/pm-suspend.log.1
> /var/log/Xorg.1.log.old
> /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
> /var/log/lightdm/x-1.log
> /var/log/lightdm/x-2.log
> /var/log/pm-suspend.log
> /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old
> /var/log/Xorg.1.log
> /var/log/syslog
> /var/log/Xorg.2.log
> /var/log/auth.log
> /var/log/kern.log.1
> /var/log/kern.log
> /var/log/Xorg.failsafe.log.old
> /var/log/syslog.1
> /var/log/Xorg.0.log
> ```

Source [How to get the previous hostname of my linux system?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20994576/3536342),
answer by [Alfe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1281485/alfe)